# Turning text file into a string (Python 3)

Tags: python, text

I want to convert a text file into a string and I was given this function to start with, which was written in Python 2:

```
def parseOutText(f):
    f.seek(0)  
    all_text = f.read()

    content = all_text.split("X-FileName:")
    words = ""
    if len(content) > 1:
        text_string = content[1].translate(string.maketrans("", ""), string.punctuation)

        words = text_string

        ### split the text string into individual words, stem each word,
        ### and append the stemmed word to words (make sure there's a single
        ### space between each stemmed word)

    return words
```

As you can see I have to add some code to this function, but it does not compile (compiler gives error, saying 'string' does not have function 'maketrans'). I am sure this code can easily be translated to Python 3 but I dont really understand what it does until the comment line. Does it simply omit punctuation and convert text to string?

Comment: I am sure its `str.maketrans()`

Comment: @Emmanuel that seems to be correct, now it gives me error saying that function takes only one argument. I simply removed second argument and it does print text, but does not remove punctuation

Comment: @Ach113 That can't be right. [`maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) optionally takes three arguments, it doesn't just take one.

Comment: Anyway, read the docs for `maketrans` and `translate`. They're not exactly the same as the Python 2.x functions, so you have to understand what they're doing if you want to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3.x [`maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) have all the basic functionality of their Python 2 predecessors, and more—but they have a different API. So, you have to understand what they're doing to use them.

[`translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) in 2.x took a very simple `table`, make by [`string.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans), plus a separate `deletechars` list.

In 3.x, the table is more complicated (in large part because it's now translating Unicode characters, not bytes, but it also has other new features). The table is made by a static method `str.maketrans` instead of a function `string.maketrans`. And the table includes the deletions list, so you don't need a separate argument to `translate`.

From the docs:

```
static str.maketrans(x[, y[, z]])
```

> This static method returns a translation table usable for `str.translate()`.
>
> If there is only one argument, it must be a dictionary mapping Unicode ordinals (integers) or characters (strings of length 1) to Unicode ordinals, strings (of arbitrary lengths) or `None`. Character keys will then be converted to ordinals.
>
> If there are two arguments, they must be strings of equal length, and in the resulting dictionary, each character in *x* will be mapped to the character at the same position in *y*. If there is a third argument, it must be a string, whose characters will be mapped to `None` in the result.

---

So, to make a table that deletes all punctuation and does nothing else in 3.x, you do this:

```
table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
```

And to apply it:

```
translated = s.translate(table)
```

---

Meanwhile, since you're dealing with Unicode, are you sure `string.punctuation` is what you want? As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation) say, this is:

> String of ASCII characters which are considered punctuation characters in the C locale.

So, for example, curly quotes, punctuation used in languages other than English, etc. will not be removed.

If that's an issue, you'd have to do something like this:

```
translated = ''.join(ch for ch in s if unicodedata.category(ch)[0] != 'P')
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found this piece of code and it works like a charm:

```
exclude = set(string.punctuation)
string = ''.join(ch for ch in string if ch not in exclude)
```

Answer (score 0):

---

change this line

```
text_string = content[1].translate(string.maketrans("", ""), string.punctuation)'
```

to this

```
text_string = content[1].translate((str.maketrans("", ""), string.punctuation)) '
```